# Javascript DateTime vs. MySQL Date and Time Zones

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, sails.js

I have a web/phonegap app that uses versions of angular + angular-bootstrap (1.2.x and 0.10.0 respectively).

On the client side I have a date picker (datepicker-popup).

On the server side I have sails.js which works with MySQL database.

My model (server side) has a date field (MyModel.js):

```
   module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        date: {
            type: 'date',
            required: true
        },
        ...
    }
   }
```

Now I have the following issue:

On the client I select a date. I am getting a js data. My timezone is +2 so if I pick 2016-01-12 in the UI, I am getting `'2016-01-11T22:00:00Z'` (which is the same time but in UTC).

Now this is sent to the server and stored in the DB.

When working on local I see '2016-01-12' saved in the `date` column in the database. When I work with a remote server, the date that is saved is '2016-01-11' (server is in AWS in EU-West - I believe Ireland).

When I retrieve that date in the client again, I am getting the wrong date (`'2016-01-11T00:00:00Z'`).

I believe this has to do with both the timezone of the server and with the data being truncated - instead of saving the full UTC date+time, it save just the date, when retrieved and parse at the client I get '2016-01-11T00:00:00Z' == '2016-01-11T02:00:00+2:00') which is the wrong date :/

Other than changing the schema/model to a full datetime (which I assume preserve the full date and be parsed correctly when retrieved in client), I am not sure what other options I have.

Is there another solution?

**Edit:**

As I wrote below doing conversion like:

`var dd = moment.utc(moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")).toDate()`

Gets you the local time but as UTC. (I think that for time zones before UTC (e.g. +2) this kind of "solves" the problem. Not sure about the other way)

For example, it will transform `'2016-01-12T00:00:00+2:00'` (== `'2016-01-11T22:00:00Z'`) to `'2016-01-12T00:00:00Z'` but this is a hack that won't work in every situation.

Comment: date doesn't store the time. If you need the time you are stuck. You can adjust for the timezone causing a difference in days by comparing the client sent value (sent datetime/to the current datetime according to the server). How much of a real difference will it make though?

Comment: @serakfalcon - What do you mean by "adjusting for timezone... by comparing the client sent value"? Also, not sure about your question/musing. Also, it is worth to note that I only care about the date but I need it to be "the same" after doing the round trip to the server.

Comment: well, the server has a time for now and the client has a time for now. You can compare the two (or just ask the user to input their timezone). Also the client could manipulate their time value. Personally i would just rely on the server value and adjust the time client side for display only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should use the `datetime` type rather than just `date` and you should always store in UTC, the client should take care of displaying it in the user's timezone.

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    date: {
      type: 'datetime',
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that by changing the schema it will fix it. I was wondering if there is a work around to it (not involving changing the schema). More generally, working as you suggested, do I need to do anything "special" on the client?

Comment: Timezones are stored in the time part of a `datetime` so there is nothing you can do with the `date` field alone. What you could do is keep the current field and create a new one that would store both date and time. Client-side JavaScript will display a UTC date in the user's timezone.

Comment: That seems then the right answer (change schema) - seems you can't avoid that - use datetime as other workarounds are bound to fail you